# Automatic encryption and decryption while logging in to a db from a program

Tags: encryption, plsql

I was thinking about this particular scenario .

Suppose I have a table named db_passwords,which stores the passwords for different databases. And now I am worried that anyone can view these passwords by writing a simple selection statement . At the same time I want to have the facility to connect to a particular database  from a program .

I got to know that there are oracle encryption packages which encrypts a particular column , by the help of which I can encrypt a particular column of a table and the logging to a db is done by the help of a key .
But I couldn't draw a clear picture of what happens in such a scenario , like ,
for a particular line of a code meant to connect to a db as follow :
sql > connect to "username" identified by "password " using ' db_name". 
In the above statement , in place of password , am I supposed to enter the key and if I enter the key will pl/sql automatically decrypt it  ?
Looking forward to your illustrations and insights on what exactly happens in such situations .

Comment: Ok, sorry, I think I misinterpreted your question. You're not making a login form, right? What you want is to store the passwords for your databases. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

Ok, I had misinterpreted your question. I thought you were creating a login form and wanted to know how to store users passwords. I now understand you simply want to store the passwords for your databases in some other database.

And well, if people that are not supposed to know the passwords for other databases have access to this "password database", then the simple answer is: **don't** store them there.

Of course, as you noted, by storing passwords in the clear in your DB, anyone will be able to see them. What you need to understand, though, is that encrypting them will not help in any way. If you encrypt them, then your application will need to be able to decrypt them (that is, your application will need to know the key). If your application knows the key, then anyone who has access to your source code is able to take that key and then decrypt the passwords that are stored in the database.

What you should do is store them somewhere only those who are supposed to know the passwords have access to. You can, for example, store them in an encrypted configuration file. The permissions for that file should be set in a way that only the correct OS users (the root, for example) can read it. Then your application will read the password from that file.

---

You should hash passwords before saving them to the database (ideally in the application level). By hashing, you transform a given input string into another one with a fixed length. The generated string will [ideally] never collide, meaning that "password123" will generate a string, while "password1234" will generate another one completely different.

When the user wants to log-in, you again hash the password he provided and compares it to the hash that is stored on the database. If they're equal, then the password is correct.

If, for some reason, you can't hash at the application level, you can use PL/SQL's built-in hash functions ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65670)).

Please note that if you hash with, say, SHA512 and store it directly on the database, there are still ways to discover the original password. To really make your passwords secure in a way no one would be able to "decrypt" them even if they have access to your DB is by hashing the passwords with a random salt. If you want to know more about that, you can read about [bcrypt](https://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

Comment: andre_ss6 : Thanks a lot for your reply . So , for every password hashed with random salt  and being provided while logging in .does pl/sql automatically decrypts it ?

Comment: No, pl/sql won't automatically decrypt it. In fact, you don't want passwords to be decryptable. If you do that, then someone with bad intentions might be able to decrypt them. You should only hash passwords (hashes are forward-only, meaning if you have a hash there is no way you can discover what string generated it).

Comment: As I said in the answer, if you want to check if the password provided from the user is correct, you can hash it again and compare to the hash that is stored in the database. If they're equal, then the password is correct.

Comment: @OzymandiasAmygdala can you please answer my comment in your question?

Comment: Yes ..the passwords for all db's are stored in a table , and while logging in to a particular db from a code  an encrypted key is to be used . I wanted to understand what happens in this scenario , I mean what it means functionally .