# A trigger that works when an attempt to log in to a DB is made

Tags: plsql, triggers

Can I write a trigger which acts as before logging to a db and takes the password being provided, decrypts it and verifies if it matches the actual password and then allows the user to log in ?

Comment: This looks like [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you're suggesting here and in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38816769/272735) looks like a very poor idea.